# jqgrid custom formatter: The custom formatter always returns the last row of the grid. Why?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, row, formatter

**Updated**
I have problems to point data with the custom formatter.

I am using jqgrid's custom formatter.

```
  function myformatter ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
  {
   ....
```

Now, my custom formatter seems to point **always on the last row of the grid**. In fact, if I get `rowObject[0]`, for example, I have the value of the [column 0, last row] of my grid.  Why?

The grid's data is correctly compiled and I already checked Json object content.

Here's my custom formatter:

```
         ......
         { name: 'act', index: 'Detail', width: 50, sortable: false, search: false,
              formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                  i = options.rowId;

                  var tst = '<a class="nau" name="nau" onClick="alert(i);return false;" href="#"></a>';
                  var det = '<a class="det" name="det" onClick="alert(this.name);return false;" href="#"></a>';
                  return tst + det;
              }
          }
         ....
```

**Update**

I noticed that the formatter works fine if I return the string I want directly (for example **`return rowObject[0]` works fine**), while I have problems **when I use variables**. Moreover, if I try to do `onclick=alert(rowObject[0])` I get an exception saying `rowObject` does not exists. I think this is the problem: if I set `t = rowObject[0]`, then the formatter use `t` as static variable instead of updating it for each row. The same if I set `i = options.rowId`, where `i` remains static...**WHY**? What I should do?

Answer (score 2):

I succeed to get it work...I must say that I feel a little embarrassed ... it was a stupid mistake. I hope we can still help some inexperienced like me, anyway. **I did not put variables outside of quotes**:

```
      ......
     { name: 'act', index: 'Detail', width: 50, sortable: false, search: false,
          formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
              i = options.rowId;

              var tst = '<a class="nau" name="nau" onClick="alert('+i+');return false;" href="#"></a>';
              var det = '<a class="det" name="det" onClick="alert(this.name);return false;" href="#"></a>';
              return tst + det;
          }
      }
     ....
```

**I quote the precious help from @Oleg**: "The code in `onclick` will be executed separately so you have to use values of the variables and not the names. For example `'onclick="alert(rowObject[0]);return false;"'` will produce error because global array rowObject is not exist. You have to change the code to use `'onclick="alert(' + rowObject[0] + ');return false;"'` which will place the value of `rowObject[0]` in the code."

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have some problems in **filling** of the grid. If `options.rowId` is the same for all rows then you fill the grid with the wrong data where the `id` is always 1.

If you will don't localize the wrong place in your code you should include the code and the test data which you use.

Moreover you should use [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) instead of `onClick`. Your current code can work now, but it will be not more work it your would change the DOCTYPE.

Comment: THX Oleg. Already checked the JSON Result and it is ok. I have different ids for each row...but now I just discovered that the custom formatter seems to point always on the last row of the grid. In fact, if I get rowObject[0], for example, I have the value of the column 0, last row of my grid! It's so strange. I tested before and I had different values for rowObject[0]...

Comment: I changed the question, because options.rowId works fine. I tought it was a problem of that property, because as a pure coincidence the value was 1. So the problem is another...THX

Comment: @Larry: If you would include test JSON data and the jqGrid definition which can be used to reproduce your problem I would try to solve the problem.

Comment: THX Oleg. Unfortunately I am working with data I cannot publish and I should make an example. Anyway, I noticed that the formatter works fine if I return the string directly, while I have problems **when I use variables**. Moreover, if I try to do `onclick=alert(rowObject[0])` I get an exception saying `rowObject` does not exists. I think this is the problem: if I set `t = rowObject[0]`, then the formatter use `t` as static variable instead of updating it for each row.

Comment: @Larry: The code in `onclick` will be executed separately so you have to use *values* of the variables and not the names. For example `'onclick="alert(rowObject[0]);return false;"'` will produce error because *global* array `rowObject` is not exist. You have to change the code to use ``'onclick="alert(' + rowObject[0] + ');return false;"'`` which will place the value of `rowObject[0]` in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg! I realized this was stupid and embarrassing mistake. In fact I was going to publish the answer! I thank the valuable cooperation as usual, you're always there! Sincerely